# ASP.Net MVC responsive web application development

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, responsive-design

I have to develop a web application which already has WCF interface implemented. We are thinking of designing responsive web site which can be accessed from all type of devices. Our earlier thought was to go mobile first and then expand that to include tablets and desktop on the design front. This part i understand that we should have seperate css for desktop and mobile, use media queries so that content gets adjusted on different screen size.

What stumps me is the performance aspect (we are developing on ASP.Net MVC platform), because the difference between web application accessed from desktop or tablet/mobile can be just seperate cshtml for them and rendering based on user agent. But both will have same controller, same action methods hence in mobile i may be requesting more data that required because of the smaller real estate and hence performance may be a bigger issue.

One way i can think of is in controllers return data based on who requested it using user agent so that it reduces the data size on the wire but that would mean too many checks and validations.

I would like to know from all of you how do you approach web application development targetted for all the devices and what performance considerations do you take.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of data binding are you planning? Server-side or Client-side? With the classic ASP.NET MVC approach using Razor and server side binding, when you choose to have a separate cshtml which is binding only a part of the data, the size of the result would still be smaller and the processing faster - but of course you also retrieved mode data then required from your service which is simply dismissed. I don't think that this would harm the device performance a lot.

Comment: thanks @thomasjaworski.com, i am looking at both the server side and client side, in service side binding i agree with you the data  including HTML transferred from server to client will be less for mobile but still I would be making a WCF call which will return more data than required and will take time for retrieval. I am also thinking of using knockout for client side binding with web api for both desktop based and mobile based views which internally hits wcf service but in this case as well i will have same issue.

Comment: Is there any other way we can develop web applications which caters to both desktop and mobile and handles performance also. I am also looking at miniSpa's but i am not really comfortable with them right now.

Comment: There is no UTOPIA. You have to make decision to trade off performance for multiple device support or take pain to create separate file for targeted device to increase performance. Mostly we develop the functionalists and research what features the user are mostly using and fine tune it to become more per-formant. As saying goes **Premature optimization is the root of all evil**

Comment: We're using KENDO UI ( http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui ) from Telerik for those projects. But this is commercial. They have great wrappers for ASP.NET MVC which generate code for you, and they do good work with data binding, it looks very optimized all the time thanks to their "DataSourceRequest" and "DataSourceResponse" strategies. Worth a look!

Answer (score 0):

Look for bootstrap from twitter, I have worked on couple of projects using that twitter bootstrap, which works for all kind of devices with single layout.